# How to properly annote Module Re expressions?

Tags: python, regex, mypy

I've been trying to type the return value of `re.compile` but mypy always complains even though I used the exact return type suggested by VS Code ie `re.Pattern[re.AnyStr@compile]`

Signature of re.compile :

```py
    (function) def compile(
        pattern: AnyStr@compile,
        flags: _FlagsType = 0
    ) -> Pattern[AnyStr@compile]
```

My code:

```py
import re
# from typing import Pattern

def dummyF(fp: str)-> dict[str, int]:
    # ...
    daterx : re.Pattern[re.AnyStr@compile] = re.compile(r""" ...
    """, re.VERBOSE)
    # ...
```

And mypy complaints

```
$pdm run startmypy
src/regex-log-filtering.py:20: error: Invalid type comment or annotation  [valid-type]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 8 source files)
```

So what is the proper way to annotate this example ?

I tried

- `daterx : re.Pattern[re.AnyStr] = re.compile(r"""`
- and `daterx : re.Pattern[typing.AnyStr] = re.compile(r"""`

The later example left me really dumb struck as the error did even make less sense to me.

```
$pdm run startmypy
src/regex-log-filtering.py:21: error: Type variable "typing.AnyStr" is unbound  [valid-type]
src/regex-log-filtering.py:21: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[AnyStr]" or "Protocol[AnyStr]" base class to bind "AnyStr" inside a class)
src/regex-log-filtering.py:21: note: (Hint: Use "AnyStr" in function signature to bind "AnyStr" inside a function)
```

Comment: `AnyStr@compile` is not valid syntax; where exactly did you get that signature for `re.compile`?

Comment: @chepner It was suggested by VSCode

Comment: `typing.AnyStr` is not a type; it's a pre-defined type variable. It's purpose is to ensure that if you pass a `str` value as the pattern, you'll get back a `Patter[str]` value, and if you pass a `bytes` value, you get back a `Pattern[bytes]` value. You are passing a `str` value, so use `re.Pattern[str]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what VSCode is doing, but `AnyStr@compile` is a syntax error; this seems to be some sort of internal representation that is being leaked as a valid type hint.

`AnyStr` is a type variable, not a type, per the documentation:

> `AnyStr` is a constrained type variable defined as `AnyStr = TypeVar('AnyStr', str, bytes)`.

This ensures two things in regards to `re.compile`.

1. The `pattern` argument can only be a `str` or a `bytes` values (or an instance of a subclass of either).
2. Whatever type you pass for the pattern fixes the return type to a corresponding `Pattern`. If you provide a `str` pattern, you get back a `Pattern[str]` value. If you provide a `bytes` value, you get back a `Pattern[bytes]` value.

For you assignment, you are passing a `str` value to `re.compile`, so you should expect a `Pattern[str]` value as a result.

```
daterx : re.Pattern[str] = re.compile(r""" ...""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: If I had to guess, the `T@function` notation may be indicating the type variable `T` bound to `function`. I guess it is debatable whether or not displaying types with a made-up syntax that is invalid in Python is a good idea, even if that representation has some merit semantically. But I agree with you that it should not be suggested as a valid type hint.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the answer and especially pointing out the notion of constrained type variable. Coming from Typescript, I'm not sure there is a similar concept...Will need to dig further

Comment: I don't really know Typescript, but using Haskell-like syntax you might write the bound-union case as `Either String Bytes -> Either String Bytes` (unrelated types drawn from the same set of two) and the constrained case as `StringOrBytes t => t -> t` (but pretend the typeclass `StringOrBytes` is closed and only `String` and `Bytes` have instances).